# What kind of stack combination to use for vue.js development[vite/nuxt/fastify]?

Tags: node.js, web-server, vue.js

I am trying to create an interactive website with vue.js framework that will interact with web3. Previously I have used node.js with packages like express in combination with css and js written from scratch for my projects but it took longer to develop. I wanted to try out a framework to build it faster and perhaps use server-side rendering for a better UI experience and SEO.

I decided on using vue.js for the front end but I am struggling to choose what to put alongside it. I am not entirely sure I even need node.js since it is going to be web3-based. Originally I thought I would have a node.js server with fastify routing but a lot of people seem to be using vite alongside nuxt 3 and I can't wrap my head around what each exactly nuxt 3 does.

I was hoping someone with vue experience could tell me what combination would be the most optimal and why.

Answer (score 0):

A good combination for building an interactive website with **[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html)** and web3 would be to use Vue.js for the frontend, and a **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/)** server with the **[Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html)** framework for the backend. Express.js provides a simple and efficient way to handle web3 interactions and route HTTP requests.

**[Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/installation/)** is a framework for building universal Vue.js applications, and it can also be a good choice if you need a framework that provides a lot of pre-configured functionality and makes it easy to get started quickly. With Nuxt.js, you can use server-side rendering for improved UI experience and SEO.

**[Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Guides/Getting-Started/)** is another option for the backend, and it is a fast and low overhead framework for Node.js. It can be a good choice if performance is a concern for your application.

Ultimately, the choice of a specific combination will depend on the specific requirements of your project, so you should consider factors such as the complexity of your application, performance needs, and development time constraints when making a decision.